# Empirically estimating big-oh time efficiency

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, big-o

### Background

I'd like to estimate the big-oh performance of some methods in a library through benchmarks. I don't need precision -- it suffices to show that something is O(1), O(logn), O(n), O(nlogn), O(n^2) or worse than that. Since big-oh means upper-bound, estimating O(logn) for something that is O(log logn) is not a problem.

Right now, I'm thinking of finding the constant multiplier k that best fits data for each big-oh (but will top all results), and then choosing the big-oh with the best fit.

### Questions

1. Are there better ways of doing it than what I'm thiking of? If so, what are they?
2. Otherwise, can anyone point me to the algorithms to estimate k for best fitting, and comparing how well each curve fits the data?

### Notes & Constraints

Given the comments so far, I need to make a few things clear:

- This needs to be automated. I can't "look" at data and make a judgment call.
- I'm going to benchmark the methods with multiple `n` sizes. For each size `n`, I'm going to use a proven benchmark framework that provides reliable statistical results.
- I actually know beforehand the big-oh of most of the methods that will be tested. My main intention is to provide performance regression testing for them.
- The code will be written in Scala, and any free Java library can be used.

### Example

Here's one example of the kind of stuff I want to measure. I have a method with this signature:

```
def apply(n: Int): A
```

Given an `n`, it will return the nth element of a sequence. This method can have O(1), O(logn) or O(n) given the existing implementations, and small changes can get it to use a suboptimal implementation by mistake. Or, more easily, could get some other method that *depends* on it to use a suboptimal version of it.

Comment: Can you avoid finding your k by just comparing runs for various input sizes?  e.g. running a binary search many times on sorted lists of size 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, etc, should eventually show the pattern you're looking for...

Comment: Maybe you could obtain a factor k for a set of one element, and calculate the different estimated values for k*O(f(n)) and find the immediate upper bound for each method? This way you have the worst case f(n)?

Comment: I wonder if it would be at all possible to parse the code to automatically calculate the possible big-Oh.  That would be pretty cool!  The method you suggested seems like the best approach though.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: In the general case, such a thing is not possible. (At least, it's not possible if the library is written in a Turing-complete language, and the question's `java` and `scala` tags imply that it is!)

Comment: The problem with that is for "small" inputs everyting is O(1). The real question is what is "small", i.e. when do you start getting benefits from your algorithm being, say, O(n log n). Some algorithms start showing their performance with inputs of size 100 while others need 10^1000: log(log(10^1000)) is less than 10

Comment: Since what you are asking for is impossible from a theoretical point of view I suggest you think of a method that produces some "slope" (like exponent) and a confidence value for it; like mean and variance for a distribution.

Comment: From what I understand your trying to do regression testing to see if your algorithms performance is getting worse. What is stopping you from doing benchmarks using data as close to reality as you can (In both contents and `n`)? This should give you much more reliable results, because in practice having better big-oh performance does not always mean better performance (think quicksort vs mergesort).

Comment: @JoãoPortela Well, first, I'm not particularly interested if the code is getting slower -- there are many reasons for that to happen which do not concern me. Second, it is not useful for me to "hardwire" this to the hardware, which would be a requirement for the kind of test you propose.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a solution.  Not sure if it's explained adequately.

Comment: Should we use the [homework] tag for this? Or [phd-dissertation]?

Comment: @Daniel -- hopfully that didn't come across as too serious. Was intended purely tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to get started, you have to make a couple of assumptions.

1. `n` is large compared to any constant terms.
2. You can effectively randomize your input data
3. You can sample with sufficient density to get a good handle on the distribution of runtimes

In particular, (3) is difficult to achieve in concert with (1).  So you may get something with an exponential worst case, but never run into that worst case, and thus think your algorithm is much better than it is on average.

With that said, all you need is any standard curve fitting library.  [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/optimization/fitting/CurveFitter.html) has a fully adequate one.  You then either create a function with all the common terms that you want to test (e.g. constant, log n, n, n log n, n*n, n*n*n, e^n), or you take the log of your data and fit the exponent, and then if you get an exponent not close to an integer, see if throwing in a log n gives a better fit.

(In more detail, if you fit `C*x^a` for `C` and `a`, or more easily `log C + a log x`, you can get the exponent `a`; in the all-common-terms-at-once scheme, you'll get weights for each term, so if you have `n*n + C*n*log(n)` where `C` is large, you'll pick up that term also.)

You'll want to vary the size by enough so that you can tell the different cases apart (might be hard with log terms, if you care about those), and safely more different sizes than you have parameters (probably 3x excess would start being okay, as long as you do at least a dozen or so runs total).

---

Edit: Here is Scala code that does all this for you.  Rather than explain each little piece, I'll leave it to you to investigate; it implements the scheme above using the C*x^a fit, and returns ((a,C),(lower bound for a, upper bound for a)).  The bounds are quite conservative, as you can see from running the thing a few times.  The units of `C` are seconds (`a` is unitless), but don't trust that *too* much as there is some looping overhead (and also some noise).

```
class TimeLord[A: ClassManifest,B: ClassManifest](setup: Int => A, static: Boolean = true)(run: A => B) {
  @annotation.tailrec final def exceed(time: Double, size: Int, step: Int => Int = _*2, first: Int = 1): (Int,Double) = {
    var i = 0
    val elapsed = 1e-9 * {
      if (static) {
        val a = setup(size)
        var b: B = null.asInstanceOf[B]
        val t0 = System.nanoTime
        var i = 0
        while (i < first) {
          b = run(a)
          i += 1
        }
        System.nanoTime - t0
      }
      else {
        val starts = if (static) { val a = setup(size); Array.fill(first)(a) } else Array.fill(first)(setup(size))
        val answers = new Array[B](first)
        val t0 = System.nanoTime
        var i = 0
        while (i < first) {
          answers(i) = run(starts(i))
          i += 1
        }
        System.nanoTime - t0
      }
    }
    if (time > elapsed) {
      val second = step(first)
      if (second <= first) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Iteration size increase failed: %d to %d".format(first,second))
      else exceed(time, size, step, second)
    }
    else (first, elapsed)
  }

  def multibench(smallest: Int, largest: Int, time: Double, n: Int, m: Int = 1) = {
    if (m < 1 || n < 1 || largest < smallest || (n>1 && largest==smallest)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Poor choice of sizes")
    val frac = (largest.toDouble)/smallest
    (0 until n).map(x => (smallest*math.pow(frac,x/((n-1).toDouble))).toInt).map{ i => 
      val (k,dt) = exceed(time,i)
      if (m==1) i -> Array(dt/k) else {
        i -> ( (dt/k) +: (1 until m).map(_ => exceed(time,i,first=k)).map{ case (j,dt2) => dt2/j }.toArray )
      }
    }.foldLeft(Vector[(Int,Array[Double])]()){ (acc,x) =>
      if (acc.length==0 || acc.last._1 != x._1) acc :+ x
      else acc.dropRight(1) :+ (x._1, acc.last._2 ++ x._2)
    }
  }

  def alpha(data: Seq[(Int,Array[Double])]) = {
    // Use Theil-Sen estimator for calculation of straight-line fit for exponent
    // Assume timing relationship is t(n) = A*n^alpha
    val dat = data.map{ case (i,ad) => math.log(i) -> ad.map(x => math.log(i) -> math.log(x)) }
    val slopes = (for {
      i <- dat.indices
      j <- ((i+1) until dat.length)
      (pi,px) <- dat(i)._2
      (qi,qx) <- dat(j)._2
    } yield (qx - px)/(qi - pi)).sorted
    val mbest = slopes(slopes.length/2)
    val mp05 = slopes(slopes.length/20)
    val mp95 = slopes(slopes.length-(1+slopes.length/20))
    val intercepts = dat.flatMap{ case (i,a) => a.map{ case (li,lx) => lx - li*mbest } }.sorted
    val bbest = intercepts(intercepts.length/2)
    ((mbest,math.exp(bbest)),(mp05,mp95))
  }
}
```

Note that the `multibench` method is expected to take about sqrt(2)*n*m*time to run, assuming that static initialization data is used and is relatively cheap compared to whatever you're running.  Here are some examples with parameters chosen to take ~15s to run:

```
val tl1 = new TimeLord(x => List.range(0,x))(_.sum)  // Should be linear
// Try list sizes 100 to 10000, with each run taking at least 0.1s;
// use 10 different sizes and 10 repeats of each size
scala> tl1.alpha( tl1.multibench(100,10000,0.1,10,10) )
res0: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((1.0075537890632216,7.061397125245351E-9),(0.8763463348353099,1.102663784225697))

val longList = List.range(0,100000)
val tl2 = new TimeLord(x=>x)(longList.apply)    // Again, should be linear
scala> tl2.alpha( tl2.multibench(100,10000,0.1,10,10) )
res1: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((1.4534378213477026,1.1325696181862922E-10),(0.969955396265306,1.8294175293676322))

// 1.45?!  That's not linear.  Maybe the short ones are cached?
scala> tl2.alpha( tl2.multibench(9000,90000,0.1,100,1) )
res2: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((0.9973235607566956,1.9214696731124573E-9),(0.9486294398193154,1.0365312207345019))

// Let's try some sorting
val tl3 = new TimeLord(x=>Vector.fill(x)(util.Random.nextInt))(_.sorted)
scala> tl3.alpha( tl3.multibench(100,10000,0.1,10,10) )
res3: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((1.1713142886974603,3.882658025586512E-8),(1.0521099621639414,1.3392622111121666))
// Note the log(n) term comes out as a fractional power
// (which will decrease as the sizes increase)

// Maybe sort some arrays?
// This may take longer to run because we have to recreate the (mutable) array each time
val tl4 = new TimeLord(x=>Array.fill(x)(util.Random.nextInt), false)(java.util.Arrays.sort)
scala> tl4.alpha( tl4.multibench(100,10000,0.1,10,10) )
res4: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((1.1216172965292541,2.2206198821180513E-8),(1.0929414090177318,1.1543697719880128))

// Let's time something slow
def kube(n: Int) = (for (i <- 1 to n; j <- 1 to n; k <- 1 to n) yield 1).sum
val tl5 = new TimeLord(x=>x)(kube)
scala> tl5.alpha( tl5.multibench(10,100,0.1,10,10) )
res5: ((Double, Double), (Double, Double)) = ((2.8456382116915484,1.0433534274508799E-7),(2.6416659356198617,2.999094292838751))
// Okay, we're a little short of 3; there's constant overhead on the small sizes
```

Anyway, for the stated use case--where you are checking to make sure the order doesn't change--this is probably adequate, since you can play with the values a bit when setting up the test to make sure they give something sensible.  One could also create heuristics that search for stability, but that's probably overkill.

(Incidentally, there is no explicit warmup step here; the robust fitting of the Theil-Sen estimator should make it unnecessary for sensibly large benchmarks.  This also is why I don't use any other benching framework; any statistics that it does just loses power from this test.)

---

Edit again: if you replace the `alpha` method with the following:

```
  // We'll need this math
  @inline private[this] def sq(x: Double) = x*x
  final private[this] val inv_log_of_2 = 1/math.log(2)
  @inline private[this] def log2(x: Double) = math.log(x)*inv_log_of_2
  import math.{log,exp,pow}

  // All the info you need to calculate a y value, e.g. y = x*m+b
  case class Yp(x: Double, m: Double, b: Double) {}

  // Estimators for data order
  //   fx = transformation to apply to x-data before linear fitting
  //   fy = transformation to apply to y-data before linear fitting
  //   model = given x, slope, and intercept, calculate predicted y
  case class Estimator(fx: Double => Double, invfx: Double=> Double, fy: (Double,Double) => Double, model: Yp => Double) {}
  // C*n^alpha
  val alpha = Estimator(log, exp, (x,y) => log(y), p => p.b*pow(p.x,p.m))
  // C*log(n)*n^alpha
  val logalpha = Estimator(log, exp, (x,y) =>log(y/log2(x)), p => p.b*log2(p.x)*pow(p.x,p.m))

  // Use Theil-Sen estimator for calculation of straight-line fit
  case class Fit(slope: Double, const: Double, bounds: (Double,Double), fracrms: Double) {}
  def theilsen(data: Seq[(Int,Array[Double])], est: Estimator = alpha) = {
    // Use Theil-Sen estimator for calculation of straight-line fit for exponent
    // Assume timing relationship is t(n) = A*n^alpha
    val dat = data.map{ case (i,ad) => ad.map(x => est.fx(i) -> est.fy(i,x)) }
    val slopes = (for {
      i <- dat.indices
      j <- ((i+1) until dat.length)
      (pi,px) <- dat(i)
      (qi,qx) <- dat(j)
    } yield (qx - px)/(qi - pi)).sorted
    val mbest = slopes(slopes.length/2)
    val mp05 = slopes(slopes.length/20)
    val mp95 = slopes(slopes.length-(1+slopes.length/20))
    val intercepts = dat.flatMap{ _.map{ case (li,lx) => lx - li*mbest } }.sorted
    val bbest = est.invfx(intercepts(intercepts.length/2))
    val fracrms = math.sqrt(data.map{ case (x,ys) => ys.map(y => sq(1 - y/est.model(Yp(x,mbest,bbest)))).sum }.sum / data.map(_._2.length).sum)
    Fit(mbest, bbest, (mp05,mp95), fracrms)
  }
```

then you can get an estimate of the exponent when there's a log term also--error estimates exist to pick whether the log term or not is the correct way to go, but it's up to you to make the call (i.e. I'm assuming you'll be supervising this initially and reading the numbers that come off):

```
val tl3 = new TimeLord(x=>Vector.fill(x)(util.Random.nextInt))(_.sorted)
val timings = tl3.multibench(100,10000,0.1,10,10)

// Regular n^alpha fit
scala> tl3.theilsen( timings )
res20: tl3.Fit = Fit(1.1811648421030059,3.353753446942075E-8,(1.1100382697696545,1.3204652930525234),0.05927994882343982)

// log(n)*n^alpha fit--note first value is closer to an integer
//   and last value (error) is smaller
scala> tl3.theilsen( timings, tl3.logalpha )
res21: tl3.Fit = Fit(1.0369167329732445,9.211366397621766E-9,(0.9722967182484441,1.129869067913768),0.04026308919615681)
```

(Edit: fixed the RMS computation so it's actually the mean, plus demonstrated that you only need to do timings once and can then try both fits.)

Comment: This is pretty cool, though I'm a bit wary of its effectiveness for log terms. I'll try it out.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - It's kind of tricky to experimentally distinguish log terms from small fractional powers, especially when things like cache locality can have a big impact on smaller sizes.  I guess I could add a log estimator and report the median error on each.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - You can now specify that it should assume a log term (see new code and new example).

Answer (score 14):

I don't think your approach will work in general.

The problem is that "big O" complexity is based on a limit as some scaling variable tends to infinity.  For smaller values of that variable, the performance behavior can appear to fit a different curve entirely.

The problem is that with an empirical approach you can never know if the scaling variable is large enough for the limit to be apparent in the results.

Another problem is that if you implement this in Java / Scala, you have to go to considerable lengths to eliminate distortions and "noise" in your timings due to things like JVM warmup (e.g. class loading, JIT compilation, heap resizing) and garbage collection.

Finally, nobody is going to place much trust in empirical estimates of complexity.  Or at least, they wouldn't if they understood the mathematics of complexity analysis.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

In response to this comment:

> Your estimate's significance will improve drastically the more and larger samples you use.

This is true, though my point is that you (Daniel) haven't factored this in.

> Also, runtime functions typically have special characteristics which can be exploited; for example, algorithms tend to not change their behaviour at some huge n.

For simple cases, yes.

For complicated cases and real world cases, that is a dubious assumption.  For example:

- Suppose some algorithm uses a hash table with a large but fixed-sized primary hash array, and uses external lists to deal with collisions.  For N (== number of entries) less than the size of the primary hash array, the behaviour of most operations will appear to be `O(1)`.  The true `O(N)` behaviour can only be detected by curve fitting when N gets much larger than that.
- Suppose that the algorithm uses a lot of memory or network bandwidth.  Typically, it will work well until you hit the resource limit, and then performance will tail off badly.  How do you account for this?  If it is part of the "empirical complexity", how do you make sure that you get to the transition point?  If you want to exclude it, how do you do that?

Comment: Your estimate's significance will improve drastically the more and larger samples you use. Also, runtime functions typically have special characteristics which can be exploited; for example, algorithms tend to *not* change their behaviour at some huge `n`.

Comment: I've never seen someone publish caveats for big-O time efficiency as you've mentioned for a hash table with a fixed-size array or an algorithm that uses a lot of memory/network bandwidth. The values I've seen always seem to assume an unlimited amount of bandwidth/memory. Granted, this isn't realistic, but perhaps it's out-of-scope for this notation.

Comment: @Gili - the question is about empirically estimating implementations of algorithms.  (You can't run an algorithm without an implementation, and you can't measure it if you can't run it.)  If we are talking about running real implementations of algorithms, then (in general) you *have to* take memory usage into account because it impacts on the time measurements.

Answer (score 7):

If you are happy to estimate this empirically, you can measure how long it takes to do exponentially increasing numbers of operations.  Using the ratio you can get which function you estimate it to be.

e.g. if the ratio of 1000 operations to 10000 operations (10x) is (test the longer one first)  You need to do a realistic number of operations to see what the order is for the range you have.

- 1x => O(1)
- 1.2x => O(ln ln n)
- ~ 2-5x => O(ln n)
- 10x => O(n)
- 20-50x => O(n ln n)
- 100x => O(n ^ 2)

Its is just an estimate as time complexity is intended for an ideal machine and something should can be mathematically proven rather than measures.

e.g. Many people tried to prove empirically that PI is a fraction. When they measured the ratio of circumference to diameter for circles they had made it was always a fraction. Eventually, it was generally accepted that PI is not a fraction.

Comment: This is absolutely insufficient to determine runtime complexity. Let's for example consider a function with execution time Y and input size X. Let `Y(X) = aX^2 + bX + C` and let the coefficients be `a = 1, b = (10 - 11 * 10^7) / 10^4, c = 10^7`. This is clearly of O(X^2) complexity, as there is an X^2 term. However, if we investigate the execution times you mentioned, we see that: `Y(1000) = 1` and `Y(10000) = 10`. So, your classification strategy would incorrectly classify this as O(X).

Comment: Sure, that function was constructed in order to fulfil `Y(1000) = 1` and `Y(10000) = 10` and the coefficients might be rather unnatural for any useful real algorithm (but it is surely possible to construct silly algorithms which approximately have that execution time function). However, the main point was that it is insufficient to assume that e.g. an O(N^2) algorithm has only O(N^2) terms in the function which describes execution time. The fact that there might be other terms will make this estimation strategy inaccurate.

Comment: You need to perform a realistic number of operations to perform the test.  If you will never do more than 10,000 operations and it scales O(n) over that range, how does knowing that you could get o(n^2) if only you attempted much more operations help you?

Comment: Pi is a ratio of two magnitudes, which qualifies it as a number and a fraction.  It is an _irrational_ number, but it can be [represented by  continued/recursive fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions).

Answer (score 5):

We have lately implemented a tool that does *semi-automated average runtime analysis* for JVM code. You do not even have to have access to the sources. It is not published yet (still ironing out some usability flaws) but will be soon, I hope.

It is based on *maximum-likelihood models* of program execution [1]. In short, byte code is augmented with cost counters. The target algorithm is then run (distributed, if you want) on a bunch of inputs whose distribution you control. The aggregated counters are extrapolated to functions using involved heuristics (method of least squares on crack, sort of). From those, more science leads to an estimate for the average runtime asymptotics (`3.576n - 1.23log(n) + 1.7`, for instance). For example, the method is able to reproduce rigorous classic analyses done by Knuth and Sedgewick with high precision.

The big advantage of this method compared to what others post is that you are *independent of time estimates*, that is in particular independent of machine, virtual machine and even programming language. You really get information about your algorithm, without all the noise.

And---probably the killer feature---it comes with a complete GUI that guides you through the whole process.

See [my answer on cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33879/98) for a little more detail and further references.
You can find a preliminary website (including a beta version of the tool and the papers published) [here](http://wwwagak.cs.uni-kl.de/malijan.html).

(Note that average runtime can be estimated that way while worst case runtime can never be, except in case you *know* the worst case. If you do, you can use the average case for worst case analysis; just feed the tool only worst case instances. In general, runtime bounds [can not be decided](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no), though.)

---

1. [Maximum likelihood analysis of algorithms and data structures](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.09.025) by U. Laube and M.E. Nebel (2010). [[preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220155691_Maximum_likelihood_analysis_of_algorithms_and_data_structures)]

Comment: Uhh, aren't we all interested?

Comment: @Indolering Apparently not, given that it took nine months for a request to pop up. :) By now, we have a website and a paper coming out; see the edit. Papers are added to the list as they appear.

Comment: The link to the paper is broken, but I guess it is to the paper "Maximum Likelihood Analysis of Algorithms and Data Structures
Ulrich Laube and Markus E. Nebel, Theoretical Computer Science, Vol. 411, No. 1 (2010), 188-212", available here: http://wwwagak.cs.uni-kl.de/component/remository/func-startdown/15/?Itemid=277

Comment: @Steohan Thanks for notifying me of the link rot. I changed the reference to the article to a more robust one. Unfortunately, I don't have an alternative link for the tool. Maybe it'll come back.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking to achieve is impossible in general. Even the fact that an algorithm will ever stop cannot be proven in general case (see [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). And even if it does stop on your data you still cannot deduce the complexity by running it. For instance, bubble sort has complexity O(n^2), while on already sorted data it performs as if it was O(n). There is no way to select "appropriate" data for an unknow algorithm to estimate its worst case.

Comment: This fails in the following ways: 1. I'm not looking at proving, but at estimating -- the halting problem relates to proofs, not to statistics, and, as a matter of fact, while it is impossible to prove completion in the general case, it is trivial to do so for the methods I'll be testing; 2. I'm not testing unknown algorithms, and I can and will select appropriate data for them; 3. it doesn't actually answer any of my questions.

Comment: But if you are testing *known* algorithms then why do need to run them to get their complexity? For all practically used algorithms their complexity is known already.

Comment: What is the possible cause of "performance regression" in your scenario? Are you're talking about things like excessive disk swapping on large data sets, for example?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov - Probably things like accidentally introducing a `n^2` term into a previously `n log n` algorithm.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov The regressions can happen with things as simple as changing inheritance order. I have a class A which extends traits T1, T2, T3, and these traits all implement a method M, but with different big-oh. If I change the order of these traits, then M on A changes the big-oh. This is no hypothetical either: there have been cases exactly like that.

Comment: @Daniel Then why not let your method return an identifier in addition to the result?

Comment: P.S. You don't even have to modify the method but have a "companion" method that returns the modifer and make sure it shares the same inheritance behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing a critical aspects of your task.

Change the terminology that you are using to: "estimate the runtime of the algorithm" or "setup performance regression testing"

Can you estimate the runtime of the algorithm?  Well you propose to try different input sizes and measure either some critical operation or the time it takes.  Then for the series of input sizes you plan to programmaticly estimate if the algorithm's runtime has no growth, constant growth, exponential growth etc.

So you have two problems, running the tests, and programmatically estimating the growth rate as you input set grows.  This sounds like a reasonable task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get 100% what you want. But I understand that you test your own code, so you can modify it, e.g. inject observing statements. Otherwise you could use some form of aspect weaving?

How about adding resetable counters to your data structures and then increase them each time a particular sub-function is invoked? You could make those counting `@elidable` so they will be gone in the deployed library.

Then for a given method, say `delete(x)`, you would test that with all sorts of automatically generated data sets, trying to give them some skew, etc., and gather the counts. While as Igor points out you cannot verify that the data structure won't ever violate a big-O bound, you will at least be able to assert that in the actual experiment a given limit count is never exceeded (e.g. going down a node in a tree is never done more than `4 * log(n)` times) -- so you can detect some mistakes.

Of course, you would need certain assumptions, e.g. that calling a method is O(1) in your computer model.

Comment: Your reasining is flawed, because you can never really conclude an upper bound from finitely many measurements. Your human guess will often be correct, though; it's just hard to do and justify numerically. Method of least squares is sth you can try together with counter data; you'll have to be prepared to try lots of functions, though, as coefficients and dominated terms heavily affect least square scores.

Comment: My reasoning is not flawed. I am saying that you cannot prove _positively_ that the structure obeys to an upper bound. But you can eliminate mistakes by observing _negatively_ violations of the assumed counts of the involved steps of an algorithm.

Comment: I can bound any finite data set by `c*log(n)` for some `c`. How do you say it is a worse bound than `d*n` in a given situation?

Comment: @Raphael: even worse than that: I can bound any *finite* data set by some (possibly very large) constant `C`, and mistakenly conclude that *any* algorithm is either O(1) or never stops. Having said that I do think that the practical side of the OP's problem is very interesting.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But let's say I implement an algorithm that according to a proof in a paper is bound takes no more than `m * log n` steps. Then I can make observations of my implementation and discard bugs by asserting that no more than `m log n` steps have been carried out. This is a bug elimination procedure, by its nature it doesn't guarantee that there are no bugs left. But I don't think that was the question. Note that `c` is not _some constant_ but a defined constant.

Comment: I see. I guess you can do that, yes -- *if* you stick to the proven algorithm to the letter. I think you won't do that in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I actually know beforehand the big-oh of most of the methods that will
>   be tested. My main intention is to provide performance regression
>   testing for them.

This requirement is key. You want to detect outliers with minimal data (because testing should be *fast*, dammit), and in my experience fitting curves to numerical evaluations of complex recurrences, linear regression and the like will overfit. I think your initial idea is a good one.

What I would do to implement it is prepare a list of expected complexity functions g1, g2, ..., and for data f, test how close to constant f/gi + gi/f is for each i. With a least squares cost function, this is just computing the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) of that quantity for each i and reporting the smallest. Eyeball the variances at the end and manually inspect unusually poor fits.

Answer (score 0):

For an empiric analysis of the complexity of the program, what you would do is run (and time) the algorithm given 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, etc input elements. You can then graph the results and determine the best-fit function order from the most common basic types: constant, logarithmic, linear, nlogn, quadratic, cubic, higher-polynomial, exponential. This is a normal part of load testing, which makes sure that the algorithm is first behaving as theorized, and second that it meets real-world performance expectations despite its theoretical complexity (a logarithmic-time algorithm in which each step takes 5 minutes is going to lose all but the absolute highest-cardinality tests to a quadratic-complexity algorithm in which each step is a few millis).

EDIT: Breaking it down, the algorithm is very simple:

Define a list, N, of various cardinalities for which you want to evaluate performance (10,100,1000,10000 etc)

For each element X in N:

Create a suitable set of test data that has X elements.

Start a stopwatch, or determine and store the current system time.

Run the algorithm over the X-element test set.

Stop the stopwatch, or determine the system time again.

The difference between start and stop times is your algorithm's run time over X elements.

Repeat for each X in N.

Plot the results; given X elements (x-axis), the algorithm takes T time (y-axis). The closest basic function governing the increase in T as X increases is your Big-Oh approximation. As was stated by Raphael, this approximation is exactly that, and will not get you very fine distinctions such as coefficients of N, that could make the difference between a N^2 algorithm and a 2N^2 algorithm (both are technically O(N^2) but given the same number of elements one will perform twice as fast).

Comment: Well, yes, that is what I said my plan was. So, where is the information about the specific algorithms I need to do it? :-)

Comment: Yea, because I can give 10 plots you can *not* reliably gauge the complexity from. Try separating `n^2` from `n^(7/3)`, for instance. We encountered stuff as weird as this (granted, on precise data sets, not noisy time measurements).

Comment: Big-Oh is always an estimation. I wouldn't even try to distinguish N^2 from N^(7/3); empirically, both look closer to N^2 than N^3, so if you wanted an empiric estimation you'd get N^2. Such fine distinctions as N^2.3333 would be theoretically derived by execution path analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share my experiments as well. Nothing new from the theoretical standpoint, but it's a fully functional Python module that can easily be extended.

Main points:

- It's based on `scipy` Python library `curve_fit` function that allows
  to fit any function into the given set of points minimizing sum of
  square differences;
- Since tests are done increasing the problem size exponentially points
  closer to the start will kind of have a bigger weight, which does not
  help to identify the correct approximation, so it seems to me that
  simple linear interpolation to redestribute points evenly does help;
- The set of approximations we are trying to fit is fully under our
  control; I've added the following ones:

```
        def fn_linear(x, k, c):
            return k * x + c

        def fn_squared(x, k, c):
            return k * x ** 2 + c

        def fn_pow3(x, k, c):
            return k * x ** 3 + c

        def fn_log(x, k, c):
            return k * np.log10(x) + c

        def fn_nlogn(x, k, c):
            return k * x * np.log10(x) + c
```

Here is a fully functional Python module to play with: https://gist.github.com/gubenkoved/d9876ccf3ceb935e81f45c8208931fa4, and some pictures it produces (please note -- 4 graphs per sample with different axis scales).

[image: sorting]

[image: bisect]

[image: cartesian product]