# How to calculate algorithm complexity by having its runtime?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm testing sorting algorithm and tried it with different amount of data.
100 thousand elements
1 million elements 
up to 10 million of elements.

I need to calculate the complexity of this algorithm by having outputs for how long every sorting took.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't really, since the time may also be dependent on the ordering of the input data.

Comment: What if I would have steps the program took to complete sorting each time? I mean 'primitive' steps.

Comment: It's still data-dependent, e.g. bubble sort ranges from O(n) if the data is sorted to O(n^2) if the data is reverse sorted. You would need to define the nature of the input data for all your test cases, and even then this would only tell you the complexity for this specific case.

Comment: If you're concerned about worst-case complexity, you can't do it that way.  For example, if you're testing some semi-naive version of quicksort, you can't expect to stumble on the O(n^2) worst case by accident.

Comment: Assuming you use pseudo-random data, measuring the time should give a good idea of time complexity, except that cache performance will have a greater effect on smaller arrays. If the sort involves dynamic allocation and  freeing of arrays (such as an inefficient top down merge sort), that will impact the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empirically estimating big-oh time efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836393/empirically-estimating-big-oh-time-efficiency)

Comment: @motleycrue see my answer. If you do the log-log plot of your running times the slope can tell you about your something program's behavior; however, you can't make any "formal" claims about the time complexity without analyzing the algorithm.

Comment: @PaulHankin it's a duplicate all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't find the running time of an algorithm without doing mathematical analysis, the empirical measurements can give you a reasonable idea of how the running time of the algorithm---or rather the program---behaves.

For example, if you have `n` measurements `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)`, where `xi` is the size of the input and `yi` is the time of the program on the input of that size, then you can plot the function to see whether it's a polynomial. In practice it often is. However, it's hard to see what the exponent should be from the plot.

To find the exponent you could find the slope of the line that best fits the points `(log xi, log yi)`. This is because if `y=C*x^k+lower order terms`, then since the term `C*x^k` dominates we expect `log y =~ k*log x + log C`, i.e., the log-log equation is a linear one whenever the "original" equation is a polynomial one. (Whenever you see a linear function in the [log-log plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot), your running time is polynomial; the slope of the line tells you the degree of the polynomial.)

Here's a plot of the quadratic function `y(x)=x^2`:
[image: Quadratic function]

And here's the corresponding log-log plot:
[image: The corresponding log-log plot]

We can see that it's a line with slope 2 (in practice you would compute this using, for example, [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics))). This is expected because `log y(x) = 2 * log(x)`.

The code I used:

```
x = 1:1:100;
y = x.^2;
plot(x, y);
plot(log(x), log(y));
```

In practice the function looks messier and the slope can (or should) only be used as a rule of thumb when nothing else is available.

I imagine there are many other tricks to learn about program behavior from running time measurements. I'll give others a chance to share their experience.