# How to evaluate program complexity in runtime?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

How can I properly and quite accurately evaluate program runtime and memory complexity just running program ?

I can run program several times using different input sizes. Can measure how long it works. But what should I do with this time further ? How to say (just seeing at "N - time" results) that this is linear or this is quadratic function ?

I think I understand how to measure memory complexity. Just get how many memory use process. And base on that decide what memory complexity is.

Comment: There is little chance without some theoretical results and reasoning. Remember for example that the average and worst-case run times of some algorithms are not the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empirically estimating big-oh time efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836393/empirically-estimating-big-oh-time-efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the comments on the question that **time and memory complexity should be reasoned** and not just only measured because of:

- Runtime not only depends on the size of the input but on the whole input and the program itself (indeed look at quicksort)
- Some O complexity behaviour will only be visible after really large (specific) input sizes

I still think **it can be a good idea in case of doubt to do a quick measurement to validate your reasoning**.

Regarding the time complexity:

Start with input size e.g. 10. This will take for example a total amount of T0.
Then give your program input with size 20. This will take for example a total amount of T1.
Then give your program input with size 40. This will take for example a total amount of T2.
Then give your program input with size 80. This will take for example a total amount of T3.
Keep on doubling until it takes too much time to do this.

Each time you double your input size, the time of your execution changes. **After a while** you will see **a trend** in your program:

If it looks like the **execution time doubles** each time you double the input, then your execution time is **Lineair**

If it looks like the **execution time quadruples** each time you double the input, then your execution time is **Quadratic**

If it looks like the **execution time is eight times** as high each time you double the input, then your execution time is **Cubic**

Of course the execution time will almost **never be exactly the double or quadruple**, but the thing about these N-time is that **you give an estimation of the behaviour when you are going towards an infinitely big input**